# Pie chart with different fill percentage

Tags: php, pie-chart

I want to ask something about jquery pie plots or pie charts. I want to make piechart/wheel where the fill percentage on each slice is not 100% like this one:

http://i1191.photobucket.com/albums/z462/rikides/a.png

I already made the basic pie chart using GD pie chart but I dont really have any idea on how to do it or where to start configuring. Can someone help me please? Im stuck on this problem for 1 week now and I have tried googling about this but I can not find any similar tutorials.

**EDIT**: I also tried using JP Graph but what I have made so far is only the basic pie chart, please let me know if its possible using JP Graph. Thank you.

Comment: http://pchart.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: @roel Is it possible to do that using pchart? I dont really have any idea. :(

Comment: me, neither, just an idea for you to check out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic), [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart), [wijmo](http://wijmo.com/wiki/index.php/Piechart) and [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/) **do not** support individual diameters for each slice. Let me know if somebody knows about an API with that capability.

EDIT: But if you are already familiar with GD and have created a basic pie, you probably just have to change the *$width* parameter for each slice in method [imagefilledarc](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagefilledarc.php).

Comment: That's what I thought of at first that it might be impossible to do that. But my employer said it is. But now that somebody also said it might be not possible then I guess I have to tell him and drop this project. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like you I search something like that.

I am using http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut and I divide the outside parts in 2, the "filled value" and the "non filled value".

Answer (score 0):

There is option in google charts for this. You have option to explode slices separately like this:

```
slices: {  
     1: {offset: 0.2},
     3: {offset: 0.3}                  
  }
```

and if you put offset to negative values it will look like this: 
[pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vo918.png)

code for this looks something like:

```
slices: {  
 1: {offset: -0.3}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

If you have exp in jquery, then i suggest you to go for [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic) a jquery based charts.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but Im not that good in jquery and I dont think that actually solved my problem. :|