# Pie-like chart with a percentage of the slices being filled

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts, pie-chart

I am trying to make chart, sort of like a pie chart, but with each slice being the same size, and having a percentage of it filled.
Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIKR1.jpg).

My question is similar to this one: [Pie chart with different fill percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064324/pie-chart-with-different-fill-percentage).
But it is 4 years old so I thought I would ask again.

I have tried using Canvasjs, Google charts, and highcharts but none of them support anything similar. I also want to have the slices functioning as buttons that can rotate the chart, having the selected one being positioned in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that result in Highcharts. Each slice should be a different series with different [size](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.size). Each series should have points in the number of the series, all points should be invisible except the one - also, it is needed for disabling [ignoreHiddenPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.ignoreHiddenPoint) so empty space will be drawn.

For example, you have an array of points `['20%', '30%']` - you need to map the points to series array:

```
[{
  size: '20%',
  keys: ['y', 'visible'],
  data: [[1/2, true], [1/2, false]]
}, {
  size: '30%',
  keys: ['y', 'visible'],
  data: [[1/2, false], [1/2, true]]
}]
```

You also might create an additional series which will be the background of the pie

```
const backgroundSeries = [{
  size: '100%',
  data: [{y: 1, color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)'}],
  enableMouseTracking: false,
  borderWidth: 0,
}];
```

For rotating the pie, you need to update [startAngle](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cpie%3E.startAngle) property

```
chart.update({
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      startAngle: startAngle
    }
  }
});
```

#### Live example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/1yjc4ogb/

[image: pie chart]